# How to flag a user for a strange behavior

Tags: support, flagging, accepted-answer

I noticed a strange behavior from a user of Math SE, I have no means to contact him directly, so I thought of notifying moderators of the site by flagging(may be).

There is nothing related to flagging a user from his profile's page, so I guess I'm left with only the option of flagging one of his Questions/Answers, which seems inappropriate to me, because to be honest neither his questions, nor answers are the subject of me wanting to flag him.

**EDIT**

I noticed this user is using the site almost only to ask questions, he doesn't even bother to upvote/accept answers on his own question

[upVote: $\frac{0}{50}$]
[accept: $\frac{3}{50}$]

I thought an act like this is not of the benefit of the site, I don't mean only showing appreciation to the guys who helped you (which is a common sense matter), but  also the way one interacts with the site may harm it.

P.S: this user is enrolled for more than a year! not a new comer [like me :) ]

Comment: So what is the subject then? Posting here will pretty much flag the behavior if you describe it. And if moderators find a fault with it they might ask for the username.

Comment: If it is a comment that is inappropriate, you can flag that, too. There is not that much else they can do other than post a question, an answer, or a comment.

Comment: Near-duplicate: [How to flag names?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15197/how-to-flag-names/15198#15198)

Comment: @CareBear: I did mention that as a (trivial) solution, but it doesn't sound honest if I flag a post that is typically not the reason of flagging!

Comment: @Conifold Edited the question, I didn't want it to go public before attracting the attention of moderators

Comment: @chouaib This behavior you described and what to do about it has been discussed multiple times at length, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13286/people-who-do-not-accept-answers-suggestion-for-dealing-with-this and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16700/award-ingrate-badges As it stands such behavior is considered acceptable, albeit discouraged, and moderators will not get involved.

Comment: What you describe as strange behavior is the new standard for MSE users.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, then? doesn't it appeal for taking an action?

Comment: See Care Bear's answer and the other comments. This is considered acceptable now.

Comment: You wrote: *I have no means to contact him directly* You can comment on some of their posts. We even have a [comment template](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4945#4945) about accepting answers.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I tend to consider it acceptable too, but asking 50 questions without a single upVote to any answer on them is a bit bizarre at least!

Comment: Bizarre $\neq$ requiring moderator action. If the questions are bad, downvote, vote/flag to close and move on.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thank you for the insights, I didn't know I can vote on the questions and move on

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> flagging one of his Questions/Answers, which seems inappropriate to me

Flagging for moderator's attention has no direct effect on the post being flagged. Flagging a post by a problematic user for moderator's attention is an appropriate way of drawing their attention to the user, even if the post itself isn't problematic. There's a free-form message that goes with the flag -- use it to explain the problem.

That said, the lack of upvotes and accept votes is **not** a valid reason to contact moderators. Users are free to vote as they wish*, which includes *not at all* as a valid option.

<sub>* as long as they do not target a specific user with the votes</sub>

Comment: I do accept your answer as it shows me how to [contact] moderators without a direct harm to a post, **BUT** I don't accept your last quote about reasons to flag! it is totally opinion-based and I do have an opinion [did you consider that the user is not aware of using upVote/downVote buttons? is it of the favorite of the site or not to be used properly? who sets the rules? ...]

Comment: You are free to communicate any perceived problem to moderators. I predict that they will decline to act, that's all.

Comment: @chouaib: Of course you are free to do whatever you want. But the moderators are not in charge on enforcing people to vote or accept, much like they are not in charge of making sure that each user checks the website at least once a day. It is not their job to notify the user of this feature either. Instead **you** can leave them a guiding comment. Be aware that unregistered users cannot vote, though, and not everyone wishes to register.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have this notification above one of my questions in which I still didn't accept answer `Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?` it is in stackoverflow, I am not sure if the policy is the same here?

Comment: Reminds me of a certain SO user... asked something like 70 questions (mostly fairly trivial but generally poorly worded) and... no accepts! (And he also has posted zero answers himself, if I recall correctly.) I just "blacklisted" him in my memory and so I never answer his questions again.